# conversion="false" in MicrositeURL / CloudPagesURL

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

I'm curious what the `conversion="false"` attribute does on links within the examples shown under **Usage** on the [MicrositeURL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/MicrositeURL.htm) and the [CloudPagesURL](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/cloudpagesurl.htm) documentation pages. I know `alias` shows up in several spots in Marketing cloud, like the _Clicks data view for example, but just not sure what the conversion attribute does.

Here are the examples, in case the docs change at all...

**MicrositeURL**

```
<p>
  <a title="MyPage" href="%%=MicrositeURL(77777)=%%" alias="ThisAlias" conversion="false">
    Click to unsubscribe
  </a>
</p>
```

**CloudPagesURL**

```
<p>
  <a title="MyPage" href="%%=RedirectTo(CloudPagesURL(77777))=%%" alias="ThisAlias" conversion="false">
    Click to unsubscribe
  </a>
</p>
```

Anyone know what it's used for?

Comment: complete guess, but I assume it is a part of the old conversion tracking feature -  which, someone can correct me if I am wrong, has kind of been pushed aside for the WAT.  I never used it, so I could be wrong.